# Resolving HTML special chars in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, htmlspecialchars

I've looked around for a solution to this problem but I can't find one.
I am trying to make a payment method for opencart.

I have two fields(ID and key) set in the admin area which I then proceed to retrieve from controller of the front end page

> (using this->config->get)

These fields are used to carry out encryption in a separate PHP file.

(Passing these as arguments)

However one of the compulsory fields (Key) has an `'&'` which is converted to `'& amp ;'`
I used

> htmlspecialchars_decode

Function to get rid of this and any other html char problems that I might face.

But I am still not getting the correct encryption. I cross checked by directly sending the key as string instead of using `this->config->get`.

Any thoughts and help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `str_replace()` to convert the `&amp;` back to `&` as you retrieve it in the controller

```
<?
// REPLACE VAR
$string=str_replace("&amp;", "&", $data);
?>
```

Comment: I tried another thing and that works even better. htmlspecialchars_decode function.

Answer (score 0):

```
html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

the function coverts all `htmlentities()` to their original characters.

**e.g.,**

```
$string = 'Cinema 30&quot; &amp; Laptop';

echo html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

will output **Cinema 30" & Laptop**